# Remote debugging in Visual Studio: VS does not send additional sources to Linux machines

Tags: linux, visual-studio

I want VS let me use remote debbuging on Linux machine. I have downloaded necccessary packages and tools for this goal, so, I've denoted output and build directories. Build directory is created always successfully, but next step is Makefile that is not run, because CMakeList.txt is not sent from Windows machine.
[image]

I text in **Additional Sources To Copy** that this file should be copied, but I cannot know a reason of unsuccessful action. Only make command notifies me that this file does not exist. I guess this problem is in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem and totally sure, that these things will exactly help you out!

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/447310/2019-makefile-project-doesnt-copy-source-on-build.html

Fix the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Makefile.targets
```

243 line, add this:

```
<Target Name="PrepareForNMakeBuild" DependsOnTargets="SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables;SetUserMacroEnvironmentVariables;_RequiresRemoteConnection;_CopySources;">
```

- Never use '~' when you denote pathes on remote machine in properties of debbuging, only like

  **/home/machine_name/project_name/$(SolutionName)/$(USERNAME)**